# Search posts by Facebook users within a specific location

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to search for users' posts based on their location? Similar to how it's done in Twitter advanced search?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=search%3Fq%3Dcoffee%26type%3Dplace%26center%3D37.76%2C-122.427%26distance%3D) page that has API call you could use. This page auto-generates an access token for you so that you don't have to make the call separately.

There isn't a way on the site itself.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook does not have this capability for an arbitrary location.  However, they do automatically create a friend list containing your friends that have their Current City in or around your city.  If you click on this friend list in the left sidebar (if it is not visible, click MORE next to FRIENDS and then click on the list named after your current city), then you will see the posts made by those friends.